# Why does using WP_Query inside a shortcode in an elementor page cause the arguments for WP_Query to get malformed?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, loop, shortcode

I am trying to embed a custom `WP_Query` inside a shortcode I have activated on one of my pages (created in Elementor). I have a Custom Post Type called 'inspector-profiles', and for some reason when I add that to my $args array, it gets either not honored by WP, or it is overwritten by something else.

I cannot see what is causing an overwrite if anything.

The code is this, so far:

```
private function isInspector() {
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        return in_array('general_inspector', (array)$user->roles);
    }
    return false;
}

public function sc_inspectorProfileData() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user = \wp_get_current_user();


    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type'              => 'inspector-profiles',
        'post_status'            => 'publish',
        'author'                 => $user->ID
    );


    // The Query
    echo '<pre>';

    $myq = new \WP_Query( $args );

    print_r($myq->request);

    if ($myq->have_posts()) {
        while ($myq->have_posts()) {
            $myq->the_post();
            print_r($myq->post);
            wp_reset_postdata();
            wp_reset_query();
        }
    }

    echo '</pre>';
}
```

When I create the arguments for `WP_Query` above, the $args array looks fine prior to running the query. When I run the query, I immediately spit out the generated SQL query, and it looks like this:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_author IN (1)  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'memberpressproduct', 'memberpressgroup', 'mpdl-file', 'ht_kb') AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 200`

My specified `post_type` is *not even in that list*. What am I doing wrong? I have tried using instances of `get_posts()`, using the `WP_Query` object, and some stuff that has been deprecated even.